# Signature for ndarray of strings in numba decorator @njit with nopython mode

Tags: python, decorator, numba

I'm trying to use signature for an array of texts in numba decorator @ njit. For example, this no-sense function:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
@nb.njit(nb.int64
         (nb.types.unicode_type, nb.int8[:], nb.types.unicode_type[:]),
         error_model='numpy')
def foo(paramText, paramArrayOfInts, paramArrayOfTexts):
    print(paramText)
    return 1

a = 'Hello'
b = np.array([1, 2], dtype=np.int8)
c = np.array(['dog', 'cat', 'me'], dtype=np.dtype('U3'))
aNumber = foo(a, b, c)
print(aNumber)
```

Shows this error:

```
  File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\Lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 574, in _explain_matching_error
    raise TypeError(msg) TypeError: No matching definition for argument type(s) unicode_type, array(int8, 1d, C), array([unichr x 3], 1d, C)
```

There is a solution if I insist in using decorators with:

```
nb.typeof(np.array(['1', '2'], dtype='U3'))
```

instead of:

```
nb.types.unicode_type[:]
```

It works, but is't not what I'm looking for.

Versions:
python 3.7
numpy: 1.18.3
numba: 0.48.0

Comment: This signature works for the latest numba: nb.typeof(np.dtype('<U3'))[:] .

Answer (score 0):

please check out this website.
https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/types.html[enter link description here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/types.html)

Comment: Appreciated your efforts and intent to help a fellow. If you can write up your answer to the OPs question would be helpful instead of posting a link.

Comment: That's the first place I checked out before asking here and it doesn't give enough information about using some numba.types. There are two numba.types that should be useful (numba.types.Array and/or numba.from_dtype). For example: numba.types.Array(np.dtype('<U3'), 1, 'C'), but it doens't work.